# Sublime text plugin is not working

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I'm using Sublime text 3 and I'm writing a simple plugin,
the problem that i have is that whenever i put `myplugin.py` in the `Packages/User` folder I get the result perfectly.

**BUT** when I move `myplugin.py` file to a folder for example `myplugin/myplugin.py` the plugin is not working anymore. I tried to see if there is any information logged to the console but I found nothing related to my problem.

Can any one tell me what is exactly the problem and what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Actually I was missing the fact that a sublime text plugin should be living in the **Packages** folder and not **Packages/User** folder

Comment: `.py` files living in `Packages/User` (or `Packages/PluginName`, for example) will be loaded as Sublime plugins. It's only when they're in subdirectories (`Packages/User/myplugin/myplugin.py`) that it won't be loaded. You *don't* want to have files just in `Packages`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to have a file `'__init__.py'` created in the myplugin folder with that file. Otherwise you will be unable to load the file as a module.

Comment: And what is the content of the  **__init__.py** file ?

Comment: @hamism - there's 2 underscores on each side and you can leave its contents empty.

Comment: This is incorrect. As long as the main `.py` file resides in the root directory of `Packages/PluginName`, it will be loaded as a plugin. No `__init__.py` is necessary.

Comment: I can't speak for Sublime Text importing modules specifically as I use vim myself; however, the python interpreter will absolutely read a directory in your path with an empty  `__init__.py` file in it as a module.

http://effbot.org/pyfaq/what-is-init-py-used-for.htm