# `Packages` folder vs. `Packages\User` folder

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

What is the better place to locate manually created plugins:

```
a) C:\Users\{UserName}\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages
```

or

```
b) C:\Users\{UserName}\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User
```

I have read several articles about ST folders structure, and it is suggested to place such plugins in User (option b) folder, because it will prevent them from overwriting during program updates. However, I am wondering if there some risks and disadvantages of using just Packages (option a).

I'm using ST3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's important to know that there is a distinction between a Sublime Text package and a plugin. [A package can contain plugin (Python) files.](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/packages.html#package-contents).

To answer your question, it is worth bearing the following in mind:

1. [`Packages/User`](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/basic_concepts.html#the-user-package) is a catch-all directory for custom plugins, snippets, macros, etc. Consider it your personal area in the packages folder.
2. [Keeping plugins directly under the `Packages` folder is discouraged.](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/plugins.html#where-to-store-plugins)

   > Keeping plugins directly under `Packages` is discouraged. Sublime Text sorts packages in a predefined way before loading them, so if you save plugin files directly under `Packages` you might get confusing results.
3. [Having plugins in a subfolder under `Packages/User` (`Packages/User/Foo`) will prevent them from working, because ST won't load them automatically.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33465589/4473405)

You could, however, create subfolders in the `Packages` folder (`Packages/Foo`), and organize your custom package contents without lumping everything together in the `User` package folder. As long as the name doesn't conflict with a plugin you have installed from Package Control, updates to other packages won't affect it. This is the technique package authors use while developing their packages.

Comment: Thank you, Keith. Also, it is useful explanation about difference between "package" and "plugin" terminology. So, the path should be `Packages\PackageName\[files]`, right? (And don't use User, except for individual files).

Comment: Hm, it's a bit inconvenient that we cannot have some directory which will store both our manually added packages and plugins, **and which will not be cluttered with system-generated files and folders (the problem, existing for "User" folder)**. What I'm talking about is something like `Packages\AllMyManualStuff\[packages and plugins]`

Comment: If someone know about such possibility, please let me know :)

Comment: You can create a folder `Packages\AllMyManualStuff` and put things in there if you want to, as @KeithHall mentioned in his answer. You just need to make sure that it's not named for an existing package that you have installed, that's all.

Comment: @OdatNurd Thanks)

Comment: Just about the terminolgy, I've done a little page on the SO's documentation about ST. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sublimetext3/8716/vocabulary

Comment: feel free to edit my answer to include a link to your documentation @math2001 :)

Comment: Also it should be noted that each package should have it's own folder under `Packages` folder, otherwise it will not work. Incorrect: `Packages\Packages Added Without Package Control\Package 1\<files>`. Correct: `Packages\Package 1\<files>`.

Comment: @KeithHall: if only the documentation (official or otherwise) were clear about point 3, or you know, if it actually worked!

Comment: @cyberSingularity feel free to log an issue at https://github.com/sublimetext-io/docs.sublimetext.io/issues (or raise a PR) regarding more clarity on the subfolder situation. Specifically, such plugins are not loaded automatically by ST as they are typically Python modules and the main Python plugin should control the load order. There's a hint about it at https://docs.sublimetext.io/reference/plugins.html#automatic-plugin-reload, but I agree its not very discoverable atm.